# The homomorphisms $\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$ are linear combinations of the functions $f_g$

Tags: geometric-group-theory

I am reading Brooks and Series, [Bounded Cohomology for Surface Groups](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271595/1-s2.0-S0040938300X01553/1-s2.0-0040938384900223/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDnNpp8AlAqInQtnRS8RDwhbzp%2FUfBjzb7srcoLYDhbCQIgJoQBDzaPJ4L2jMA6gYAWOyeCGgPeeyTZyh1BezOlrJMqgwQI4v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDOGXFerko%2FJoXqfYGSrXA81GF36mzgVaw8iJNVqr9fYF9fAXJCClKKIoAiFmyagzF5JTd0Afu%2BMyi6682uJrNPB0tpToptAZcdh5c0ls1%2BT3uBSdxWPwCqijoJJF560CD3XlllxhFaos7u%2FOOUN%2B2FDmb7M2Q1CXKsKVFYPJ61YZXwhWr0wTL3WF8JZY8WCTyiVYN6qUgr0brlSif%2FKzOvwpgJOohB%2FUcGljGjGJ2OHkhpSHNCDJokdv0jPrYUEIIyWh9PUTgRbz3hcGrj2YCrIXz7sarXEVATaXiy%2BGlfzyRORMO64ttjk3xxc64Q1wa5mu6rm9lImvaItKOj%2FhwgPTnIuvTrPVzEjc5jqNEYfdQMzx8VLWnd%2FmOKwwztRmX5KSYcHEVYsP1ch1KRNk6CZ6I5hbsoVIFdkrqdhMn4VqLvyvZPHU55HOhziik7YAQMyAhnP%2FNpxC2mEMMy1lriLSauK8f9zdrme7tQF3pxdbMWMAZTZtWMfNNeNyWP7xBJR%2Fu1LU14c5G3mHRCymG8JCYsT6gkyf1aNj9GYYPdFIAn4KwOGSdjrhu3zdi9BuOdIYcdncU6rcIRWSAht8TUXaDqxZ6ePwhGYy4olGVSxbgV7R8IomIQYE%2FjmKsLVnSmoczVIyJzD%2BpbuJBjqlAQxVxe3hXPw1B0hHFWQlmdXXryBN%2Fk8JhxxflooS2b0pyBkoPVdNUKlCRTRl7USkyuZ5QAbawLLj5JTQgI5M5lMeqjyvmy27qs8CE8eSr%2Bp4r1%2FIyHQmqJg12h1gwLiHIfbFDnuSpvFcCRraR%2FUEHveM6y5nHLwlwHbk8sjviYu6%2BrBCTSrlZpt5UySkktwMywuwBvIVZ15FX7RKiv%2BmDRjtMJ2vQw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210901T015052Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSV6XDG5J%2F20210901%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=bb005c60048c4269adc0cbbb4c55dbcce761355e428e8081255c3ef5c8d28c95&hash=d5ac9ce83e17956a938d7c0a25a181e79f4cbf96f2efcb1c0b16ed4fce96a814&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0040938384900223&tid=spdf-15f692da-de15-4ca3-99fd-7888aa483ff1&sid=f28b616a7176614ee148fa472bff539f5189gxrqa&type=client).

At the end of the first paragraph on the last page, it says "the homomorphisms $\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$ are linear combinations of the functions $f_g$, $g\in\Gamma_0$", where $\Gamma_0=\{a_i,b_i,a_i^{-1},b_i^{-1}\}_{i=1}^g$ is the set of generators of the surface group and $f_g=2(h_g-h_{g^{-1}})$. Here $h_w(x)$ means counting the word $w$ inside the word $x$ (to my understanding).

I have problem understanding this... Is there a proof of this fact?

Comment: Where are you getting those long equations from? They don't seem to have much to do with the quoted statement. For example, why would one expect the function $f_{abc}$, which is not a homomorphism, to obey an equation such as you have written?

Comment: @LeeMosher Now I think of it, I mistakenly thought $\sum m_if_{w_i}$ is a homomorphism, while they are saying $\sum m_if_{w_i}-l$ is a homomorphism instead. But still, I think I am confused with $C^1(\Gamma,\mathbb{R})$. I thought it is the same as $\hom(C_1(\Gamma),\mathbb{R})$, while they should be just set maps on $\Gamma$? Or do the "homomorphisms" in the paper mean group homomorphisms? I think if they are saying group homomorphisms, I might see how it is a linear combination of the $f_{w_i}$'s...

Comment: Let me suggest that you write a more targetted post directly focussed at some more particular question, perhaps some question about some particular passage in the paper. Your latest comment kind of jumps all over the place, and I cannot quite discern what you need to know. I don't want to have to rewrite the theory of quasimorphisms for you, since it is well laid out in that paper already.

Comment: $f_g$ is only defined for $g\in\Gamma_0$, so $f_{abc}$ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks to you both!!! I guess for this post I just aimed to understand the sentence in the title. I deleted my wrong understanding in the post. I didn't know "quasi-morphisms", but I think I've found something...